ERROR: Expected end of line, Any ideas?
I am trying out something for Photoshop using apple scripts and I am getting this error: 628:632: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found command name. (-2741)
does anyone know what could be wrong?
This is the code:
import subprocess


def run_applescript(script):
    subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', script])


script = '''
-- Specify the paths for the image and the LUT cube file
set imagePath to "/Users/po/Desktop/sc.png"
set lutPath to "/Users/po/raw/luts/Show.cube"

tell application "Adobe Photoshop 2020"
    activate
    
    -- Check if Photoshop is running
    if not (exists document 1) then
        -- If Photoshop is not running, open it
        do shell script "open -a 'Adobe Photoshop 2020'"
    end if
    
    -- Wait for Photoshop to finish launching
    repeat until application "Adobe Photoshop 2020" is running
        delay 1
    end repeat
    
    -- Open the image
    open imagePath
    
    -- Wait for the image to open
    repeat until exists document 1
        delay 1
    end repeat
    
    -- Create a new adjustment layer (Color Lookup)
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop 2020"
        tell current document
            set adjustmentLayer to make adjustment layer at end with properties {type:"color lookup"}
        end tell
    end tell
    
    -- Apply the LUT cube file to the adjustment layer
    tell adjustmentLayer
        set lookupTableFile to lutPath
        set color lookup properties to {lookup table file:lookupTableFile}
    end tell
end tell


'''

run_applescript(script)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you haven’t found this tool to debug AppleScript - I can’t recommend it enough - try free and only pay when it makes sense.  https://latenightsw.com/

There's no need for do shell script "open -a 'Adobe Photoshop 2020'". You already started Photoshop when you did activate earlier, and everything after that is being executed by the Photoshop application. There's also no need to wait for it to finish launching.

Remove those unnecessary blocks. Then construct the script incrementally until you get the error, and you'll know the problem is in the code you added last.
